# Edit Source code and use it at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema

Basically I want to extract JsonSchema from Json string at runtime(Can't use Tools), found no library to do this. 
Other way is to first Convert JSON to Class(Found one Open Source Code) then create JsonSchema using JSON.NET as below.

```
var generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Rootobject));
```

But Rootobject class is not known at compile time, so I'm getting compile time error. Is there any other way to do this? Please help

Comment: did you try using dynamic object , reference :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object
PS: if i misunderstood your question please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to use your code to generate a class's source code, compile that using the CodeDOM, load the generated assembly and generate the Schema for that object then.

Information on using the CodeDOM to build an Assembly at runtime can be found  on MSDN here: [Generating and Compiling Source Code from a CodeDOM graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06(v=vs.110).aspx) (it's the second headline you'd be interested in).

Information on how to load the Assembly can be found on MSDN here: [How to: Load Assemblies into an Application Domain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope that helps in solving your problem.

Comment: I'll look into it and hopefully I will post the Working Code soon ;)